# Why is CORS not being enabled in my API?

Tags: javascript, c#, cors, asp.net-web-api2

I have a simple API (Web Api 2), in which I try to get familiar with Bearer authentication.

I can confirm that the token endpoint is working with Postman and simple ajax calls:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:51802/token",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    data: {
          grant_type: "password",
          userName: "foo",
          password: "password123"
    }
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}).fail(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

The client, which is a fairly simple knockout application uses the npm http-server to run, so I need CORS enabled on my API, to make those calls. However, none of what I try, seems to have any effect (Meaning no CORS headers present):

```
//1
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
     config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"));
     /*remaining out of the box configuration*/
}

//2
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    /*remaining out of the box configuration*/
}
```

Using the same javascript call as above from within the web application running the node http-server always results in 2 errors:

1. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) (`{"error":"unsupported_grant_type"}`)
2. XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:51802/token. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

Inspecting the headers in Postman, I cannot find any CORS related entries:

```
Cache-Control →no-cache
Content-Length →641
Content-Type →application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date →Fri, 17 Mar 2017 06:58:54 GMT
Expires →-1
Pragma →no-cache
Server →Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Set-Cookie →.AspNet.Cookies=CiveOcfPNVqn_sVcJSQdi7VuqcleAd_Z9TD5Fff5m3lI3oZ3uVmThZHClXIAgwqByGoOlhfaCSHM8SwQ_GylajAnPdb0Ta6jmSl-M-CDnNYGdghibUWzSn_6-wgnNov_FGjkX8DSFoFvIYshFuppzbauS8MvUQkiDGVQg5pOvplaqcjD00SnsQMYssd5XQJGtb4NE35rOiF0Uk6hE45QxjAIUaq9LGVy; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By →ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles →=?UTF-8?B?QzpcUHJvamVrdGVcWWFpYlxZYWliLkFwaVxUb2tlbg==?=
```

I'm fairly sure I'm missing some very basic configuration on either my API or the client, but I can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was indeed the "client".

The correct setting was to use `app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);`

After this I made sure, the http-server (`http-server -c-1`) did not cache any files and deleted all temporarily stored files from Google Chrome. 
Without this, old javascript code would be served, which was one cause of those error messages.

Now I was able to authenticate using the code in the question and then access protected resources:

```
$.ajax({
     url: "http://localhost:51802/api/values",
     type: "GET",
     crossDomain: true,
     headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer U90P0Lh-Q8ZeMyZXDzLSQPCfJVIXlmj94GHjLUY0M_B_Zfm-jojao7lUjZvcz_pLerS5BKwMrQk29eZI618mUZyhZ3gm0bjAy3WCZ4dYS1pv4vTaR8re6i8uriwsmtkm3FMwMxWOIPR0thLyYsjFQ7XM8s7K3pkUiIuEixFT8mG8wMnHe1FD1EoJxhadT7gbmYhm-MRO2cNuf2K8gx4EOyjwM2bsgdhtARA3oSDq5SezFRxLzDtZ32PfSpG61v9jOqIiJ0pWdtgeDSY2W7EusVzyDu0V7MB8kAc4uqNyjlCZFDiEn-mLvJkcqXpRf..."
     }
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}).fail(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**For enabling CORS, we need to to set the origins, headers, methods for all controller.**

We can do this by either of following two methods.

**1. Adding a attribute to controller(s)**

```
 `[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class MyController : ApiController
    {`
```

**2. Configure this in our Web.config file**

```
`<system.webServer>
     <httpProtocol>
       <customHeaders>
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
       </customHeaders>
     </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>`
```

Comment: As you can see from my question, I have that package already installed and I try to enable CORS globally, not on a per controller or per action basis

Comment: For enabling CORS, we need to to set the origins, headers, methods for all controller, we can do this by either by attribute or web config approach, updated answer may help.